# how to connect raspberry pi to google home app?

Tags: pixel

How am I to connect my Raspberry Pi 3 (PIXEL desktop) to the Google Home app if it already has Google assistant on it?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this. Here is a list of features that are coming soon:
https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/release-notes
I hope that helps!

Comment: You can run almost any android app on Linux using snap and Anbox.
Check out this article [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/run-android-apps-games-linux/).

Comment: Check these two links I believe that they'll be answer to your question: [HomeBridge on Raspberry - Pi](https://github.com/nfarina/homebridge/wiki/Running-HomeBridge-on-a-Raspberry-Pi) [HomeBridge and Google Home](https://www.reddit.com/r/homebridge/comments/7jbg90/homebridge_and_google_home_google_assistant_or/)